# Sql Transaction for POS

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am developing a POS for a pharmacy the scenario is like this:
1. a user select category and then Item, then the item will be pass to DataGridview, the use can increase and decrease the value of item.
2. the user select customer and other necessary information.
3. the user press the pay button and all insertion to stock, account register, sales invoice will be done in back of this pay button.
P.S: this system is multi User, mean Lan based.
Now, my question is that, I am trying to tell that system that check with still no changes come to qty of item in stock, if come rollback else commit.
Can I use Sql Transaction or no?
Thanks in Advance for answer.

Comment: Not sure if I'd do this rollback with a SQL transaction...I'd look into code to check quantitiy before the insert is made or a trigger on the table (might be a bad idea if the load on this table is huge).

Comment: You have to use SQL transaction of course. You can better use stored procedure, in that perform all the insertion/update. Before calling commit transation, check the stock again, if it is valid then commit else rollback